# Analytics for a new Stack Exchange site

Tags: discussion, support, analytics

If I create a new QA site using Area 51, can I access the Google Analytics data generated by it, or are those only for the Stack Exchange developers to see?

Answer (score 2):

Moderators can also see the data, so you would need to put yourself forward for either pro tem moderator (in the case of a site still in beta) or nominate yourself when an election is held.

That assumes that you are successful course.